# Lint node.js code on save

Tags: node.js, eslint

I want to lint my node.js code when saving the file (so I don't have to to run `npm run eslint` manually). If I were to write the frontend, I'd use webpack to bundle and lint my files on save. However, as I currently don't need to bundle my Node.js code (or do I?), I'm not sure if this is the way to go or if I have any other alternative?

How is this usually done with Node.js? I wasn't able to find any answer to that question using Google's or Stackoverflow's search but I might have looked for the wrong thing.

Comment: Not sure if this is useful, but I noticed that you could also just use nodemon for that task: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588458/how-to-do-linting-using-nodemon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use gulp or grunt or any other build tool to watch your project and run es-lint on save.

Or you could just use a text-editor or ide with a js-lint plugin.

Comment: Thanks, if I use those tools, do they also allow me to reload the node server on save – similar to how nodemon and similar tools work?

Comment: Yup, you can use a grunt or gulp watch task to reload the server after error free linting.   You could probably set up webpack to do it as well, just leave out the build tasks.